# How to read a shapefile using Julia?

Tags: shapefile, julia

I am starting to learn Julia and I am wondering how to read a shapefile? Is it as straightforward as with other languages (*e.g.* Python or R)?

Answer (score 2):

First, add the [`ArchGDAL.jl`](https://github.com/yeesian/ArchGDAL.jl) package by pressing `]` inside a `julia` environment and typing:

```
add ArchGDAL
```

Then, to read a Shapefile:

```
using ArchGDAL

dataset = ArchGDAL.read("test.shp")
layer = ArchGDAL.getlayer(dataset, 0)
```

Then, you will be able to access individual features and their respective attributes and geometries (very similar to the GDAL Python bindings). Documentation can be found on: http://yeesian.com/ArchGDAL.jl/latest/features/